# Widgets not showing up in non english language

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have a few wordpress blogs what uses the same theme folder (for convenience).
One of these blogs is in english and the rest is in russian, polish etc.
Edit: Just saw that the widget is showing up in polish but not the other languages.

I have created a few widgets and for some reason they are not showing up in the other languages. Just in english.

Does anyone know why?!

Answer (score 0):

That might be because of META charset of page. Change meta charset to utf-8 or language you support

Comment: the meta charset is utf-8 on all sites. The only thing that differs is <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">, <html dir="ltr" lang="pl-PL">